# Compiling with distutils: /usr/lib is added as a file to compile

Tags: python, linux, gcc, distutils

When compiling my extension I get a linker error saying `/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib: No such file: File format not recognized`. I noticed `/usr/lib` is added as a file to the gcc command for some bizarre reason. Here are the commands and their output:

```
python setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
building 'test' extension
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes /usr/include -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c test.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/test.o
gcc: /usr/include: linker input file unused because linking not done
gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions /usr/lib /usr/include build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/test.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/test.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib: No such file: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I stripped the `setup.py` from everything but the basics leaving me with this:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

setup(
     name = "test", 
     ext_modules  =  
         [
         Extension("test",
             sources = [
             "test.c"
             ]
         )
         ]
)
```

And here is the `test.c`:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *
py_run_executable(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
     char *file_path = NULL;

     if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &file_path))
         return NULL;

     return PyInt_FromSize_t((size_t) 1);
 }

 PyDoc_STRVAR(pet_cpu__doc__, "Testing module");
 PyDoc_STRVAR(run_executable__doc__, "Function doc");

 static PyMethodDef pet_cpu_methods[]  =  {
     {"run_executable", py_run_executable, METH_VARARGS, run_executable__doc__},
     {NULL, NULL}
 };

 PyMODINIT_FUNC
 initpet_cpu(void)
 {
     Py_InitModule3("test", pet_cpu_methods, pet_cpu__doc__);
 }
```

### What I have tried and my thoughts

As you can see I have tried to eliminate problems with the extension itself and just keep the bare minimum. It seems there some kind of configuration fault in how paths are setup with `python` or `distutils`. If I run the command which fails and remove `/usr/lib /usr/include`:

```
$ gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.6/test.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/test.so
```

Running this command the linking is performed and the `*.so` is produced. It seems the main problem is with `distutils` and not the compilation itself.

**My question is, why are these two paths added?**

The computer running this is a new Debian 6.0 install with python 2.6.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment variable `CFLAGS` is respected if available.

If you look under `Tweaking compiler/linker flags` @ http://docs.python.org/install/ it is clearly describes as the default behaviour in regards to environment variables.

Comment: Thank you, HonkyTonk. I obviously need to read more about exactly how `CLFAGS` is generally used and environment variables in general.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was with environment paths for my user. I tried running the same commands as root which dot-files has not been changed at all, **and it worked fine.**

The problem was that when `CXXFLAGS`, `CFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS` are set manually in the `.profile` they are included in the `gcc` commands. Here are the problem lines in my `.profile`:

```
export CFLAGS="/usr/include"   
export CXXFLAGS="/usr/include"  
export LDFLAGS="/usr/lib"
```

Why these were added was because I needed the paths set to compile another project which didn't use a `autoconf` or `configure`-script.

I'm marking this as the answer. If someone comes up with the reason to exactly why `distutils` adds these paths to the command I'll accept that answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. As described by @rzetterberg, it's the issue of `LDFLAGS`.

Turns out that I set `LDFLAGS` in `~/.bashrc` as:

`export LDFLAGS=/some/path/cuda/cuda-9.0/cuda/lib64`

And it should be amended as:

`export LDFLAGS=-L/some/path/cuda/cuda-9.0/cuda/lib64`